# Cannot get black around mesh to be transparent in Blender 2.8

Tags: texturing

I was following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbiuwaJ6PT4
and I couldn't get the rips in the flag to become transparent instead it kept showing up as black on the edges:
[image]

I tried to use nodes but nothing really change, is possible for an object to look solid and have transparency where needed in blender 2.8?
Also, I'm using the Eevee render and plan to import to unity, here is my photoshop work just in case the problem lies there:[image]

Here is my Blend file:
[image]

Comment: Did you export and import in a format that supports transparency?

Comment: I just tried to export as a .png and replace the .psd image with the .png one but nothing changed.

Comment: Could you add your .blend by uploading it to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? Would make it quite a bit easier to help you

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5916" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5916/)

Comment: Please include your texture in your .blend too, else we will see a pink texture instead of the cloth. You can do this by going to File -> External Data -> Automatically pack into .blend. Also, please edit your question with the link to the .blend instead of commenting

Comment: I tried to change the blend mode to additive while it does get rid of the black around the flag it also becomes transparent.

Comment: Change the color of the transparency node to white, I get this result from it: https://imgur.com/a/dh84DDH

Comment: Alright, just tried it out and it worked for me too. Should have tried that out first in hindsight but anyway, thank you for your help it is much appreciated!